# Identification of light and sound part

Tags: piece-information, part-identification

Found the following car/space craft body this weekend. It takes two AA batteries and has three buttons for different sounds and light sequences. It is marked k8. The part is about six inches long, has LEGO embedded on proper spots but no part number.  I can send a picture if anyone has an idea.  Thank you for the responses it is exactly what is shown in the first answer, and inspectors body.  Now I know.  Next time I will work on imbeddong a pic.
Ted

Comment: Welcome to Stack Exchange, Ted. Please embed a picture in your question so we can get you the proper answer. LEGO has made so many pieces over the last 50+ years that identifying one based on a description is nearly impossible. Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

Sounds like electric, light & sound 4 x 20 x 5 insectoid stinger.

Part# top: [x239top](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=x239top#T=C&C=10)

Part# bottom: [x239bottom](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=x239bottom#T=C&C=10)

[image]

[image]

Comment: I was suspecting the same ... would like to see a picture to confirm this.